# how find the max after a group by sum

Tags: python, pandas

sample data set as

```
Category         Product Name  Sales       Quantity
Furniture        AAA           100         2
Tecno            DDD           250.56      3
Office Supplies  CCC           278.65      2
household        BBB           957.5775    5
household        BBB           22.368      2
Office Supplies  CCC           48.86       7
Tecno            DDD           7.28        4
Furniture        AAA           907.152     6
Furniture        AAA           18.504      3
Office Supplies  CCC           114.9       5
```

I need to get the product name that sold most

```
df_com_sales.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum().max(axis=0)
```

but this only the number and i tried

```
df_com_sales.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum().max(axis=0)
```

this also didnt work

the answer should be =   CCC

OR

CCC     14

Comment: What answer do you get? Also see edit for better readability

Comment: df_com_sales.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum().idxmax()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the product that sold the most with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category': ['Furniture', 'Tecno', 'Office Supplies', 'household', 'household',
                 'Office Supplies', 'Tecno', 'Furniture', 'Furniture', 'Office Supplies'],
    'Product Name': ['AAA', 'DDD', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'CCC'],
    'Sales': [100, 250.56, 278.65, 957.5775, 22.368, 48.86, 7.28, 907.152, 18.504, 114.9],
    'Quantity': [2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 5]
})

product_sum = df.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum()
max_product = product_sum.idxmax()
print(max_product)
# CCC
print(product_sum[max_product])
# 14
```

Comment: Can i get it from one code ?  without product_sum =

Comment: @lousia What do you mean "from one code"? If you mean one line, you can do `df.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum().idxmax()`, which will only give you `CCC`. But if you want to get the summed amount from the product, you need to retrieve that from the same series.

Comment: `df.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum().sort_values().tail(1)` if you want one line with both

Comment: @ALollz That's nice too. It does require a bit more of work to sort, though. Tbh, it's a bit surprising that there is no operation to simply get the maximum of a series with its index.